# Getting the max occuring value of a list of dates

Tags: r, statistics

I have a vector of dates:

```
> (dput(head(list$date, 35)))
c("18.12.2003", "06.04.2005", "06.04.2005", "07.04.2005", "27.05.2005", 
"16.06.2009", "16.06.2009", "21.12.2009", "22.12.2009", "09.06.2011", 
"14.06.2011", "20.12.2011", "20.12.2011", "04.02.2008", "27.03.2009", 
"01.04.2009", "15.12.2009", "23.09.2005", "19.06.2005", "20.06.2005", 
"20.06.2005", "20.06.2005", "21.06.2005", "31.05.2005", "24.01.2007", 
"24.01.2007", "24.01.2007", "15.05.2007", "16.05.2007", "16.05.2007", 
"18.05.2007", "21.05.2007", "21.05.2007", "22.05.2007", "22.05.2007"
)
```

By plotting this I can see the max value:

```
hist_data <- hist(as.Date(list$date, '%d.%m.%Y'), breaks="days", freq=TRUE)
```

THe occurency can be obtained by:

```
(max(hist_data$counts, '%d.%m.%Y'))
```

However, I would like to get the date of this max occuring value. Is it possible to max the max  `max(...)` with the date histogram?

I appreciate your answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `table` function:

```
tab <- table(as.Date(list$date, '%d.%m.%Y'))
names(tab)[tab == max(tab)]
# [1] "2005-06-20" "2007-01-24"
```